Why do French parties keep changing their names?
Macron's party was

first founded in 2016 as En Marche!
renamed in 2017 as La République En Marche!
renamed in 2022 as Renaissance.

Union pour un mouvement populaire was renamed in 2015 as Les Républicains.
Front National was renamed in 2018 as Rassemblement National. (I guess this is more understandable as part of Marine Le Pen's efforts to rebrand and distance herself from her father.)
(Is this a French tradition or just some recent novelty?)

En marche ! to Renaissance expresses the sentiment of a movement
En marche ! started off stressing their existence as a movement, rather than a political party. The name change to La République en marche ! happened after the 2017 presidential election with Macron being elected President; the name change acknowledges that while still wanting to keep it's ostensible origins as a gassroots movement.
It was renamed to Renaissance ostensibly to reflect embracing 'the choice of enlightenment against obscurantism'.
As a relatively new movement / party, they lack the inertia or baggage that older and more established parties have; and can use name changes like this to show (claim) they have the weight of the country behind them (by adding in La République); and later to try to establish themselves as forward-looking and progressive (Renaissance) rather than conservative or regressive.
UMP's name change was part of a bigger change in structure driven by Nicolas Sarkozy
Wikipedia notes:

The UMP's (Union for a Popular Movement) change of party name and of party structure was one of the promises made by Nicolas Sarkozy during his campaign for the UMP presidency in 2014.

There is a more detailed contemporaneous write-up in Politico, which explicitly draws a parallel between the name change of UMP to the Republican Party in the US.
However, WP states that this was another attempt at showing unity amongst factions:

Nicolas Sarkozy wanted to change the name of the party in order to showcase the reunification of the different political views, from the social Gaullism of Henri Guaino to the right line of Patrick Buisson, into "one family".

The other option («Le Rassemblement») was rejected.
Note that UMP was itself only founded in 2002.
Front National distanced itself from disappointing results and its past
The answer on the RN/FN-specific QA by Denis de Bernardy starts with two explanations:

Officially she wanted something more inviting, that would a) bring people together more - Hence Rassemblement National (National Gathering) vs Front National (National Front, as in it's a war) - and b) relieve the party of the stigma associated with its name (because it is widely perceived as racist and antisemite, because of the despicable reputation of its founder and his henchmen, etc.).

Wikipedia also notes:

At the conclusion of the party congress in Lille on 11 March 2018, Marine Le Pen proposed renaming the party to Rassemblement national (National Rally) while keeping the flame as its logo. (...) Rassemblement national had already been used as the name of a French party, the Rassemblement National Français (...) The name had also been used by the FN previously, for its parliamentary group between 1986 and 1988.

Marine Le Pen was heavily defeated in the 2017 presidental elections, with FN doing relatively poorly in the subsequent parliamentary elections.
The Front National name was used from 1972 until that point.
Other parties

Parti socialiste has had their name since 1969
La France Insoumise is another recent party, founded in 2016, but which has kept its name since then


As a general explanation of the observed pattern could one maybe say that French just like to adapt names of their parties from time to time? Maybe continuity and experience are valued less than novelty and dynamics?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution That may well be a pretty reasonable thing to say, but I didn't want to make a value judgement :) The answer as it stands deals chiefly with the parties ( / «movements») mentioned in the Q and mostly their recent name history, but I'd like to expand this into a fuller answer that deals with pre-2016 in more detail
